# Are heroku apps anonymous?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

If I have made 2 different heroku apps, can someone who randomly sees one also find the other and know that I made it? (They are not linking to each other of course)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [Heroku Website](https://www.heroku.com/what) you will notice that it is a deployment service for developers equipped with all required tools. On Heroku there is no way to find who is registered with Heroku or list of registered apps on Heroku just like Github.

So **Github** has a different service model, and we can easily search any repo, any author (if public). On Heroku there is no area or option to search like that.

Except that, if you are using Heroku for free and their free domain, then the prefix in start of your free domain name will let others know that you are using Heroku platform (with free package or have not configured real domain yet).

**Twilio** a famous SMS API service provider, has their chat service hosted on Heroku, they didn't configured the domain, hence I noticed Herokuapp in start of their chat window URL, which let me know that they are using Heroku.

Comment: But even if they know my app is on herokuapp they could never find my other deployed heroku apps, correct?